# Hermitian Matrix multiplied by complex numbers

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, self-adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

I have a question regarding self-adjoint(hermitian) matrices, and their properties when multiplied by an imaginary number.
The matrix in question is:
$$\mathbf{A}  = c
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&2i&0\\
0&-2i&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\\
\textit{where} \; \mathbf{A}^\dagger=\mathbf{A} $$
This should be pretty simple to answer to, but I am having a brain fart at the moment: if we assume $c=\frac{i}{2}$, then:
$$\mathbf{A}  = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\\
\textit{where} \; \mathbf{A}^\dagger\neq\mathbf{A} $$
Do hermitian operators stop to be so if multiplied by a complex number?

Comment: Yes. Multiplying a Hermtian matrix by a complex number does not necessarily give you a Hermitian matrix.

Answer (score 2):

When $A$ is Hermitian, we have $(cA)^\dagger-cA=c^\dagger A^\dagger-cA=(c^\dagger-c)A$. Therefore $cA$ is Hermitian if and only if $A=0$ or $c$ is real.